# Equivalence Classes

Tags: metric-spaces

The scenario is a follows:

I am given a set $X$ along a map $d$ defined as $d:X \times X  \to \Bbb R^+$ for all $x,y,z \in X$  with the following properties:

$d(x,y) =0 \Leftarrow  x =y \\
d(x,y) =d(y,x)\\
d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(y,z)
$

The follow equivalence relation is also defined:

$x \tilde{}y \iff d(x,y) =0 $

$\delta$ is defined as such $\delta([x],[y]) = d(x,y)$

I suppose to prove the $\delta$ is well defined; in other words  if $[x] =[a]$ and $[y]=[b] $ then $\delta ([x],[y]) = \delta ([a],[b]) $.

I am generally stuck in this case.

I would rather some hints on how to solve this problem in a more general setting

Comment: This isn't a very interesting equivalence relation...

Comment: Did you mean to omit the first property?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein No, I know that this is not this interesting

Comment: well, there's only one $x$ and $y$ for each $[x]$ and $[y]$, so well-definedness is a non-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to check, that if $[a]=[x]$ and $[b]=[y]$, then $\delta([a],[b])=\delta ([x],[y])$. Using the triangle inequality we obtain: $\delta([a],[b])=d(a,b)\le d(a,y)+d(b,y)=d(a,y)\le d(a,x)+d(x,y)=d(x,y)=\delta([x],[y])$, since by definition $0=d(a,x)=d(b,y)$. The reverse inequality can be shown similarly.

Answer (score 1):

**(This answer is based on the old version of the OP's question.)**

This is just explicitly writing out my remark in the comments.

As you say, we need to assume $[x]=[a]$ and $[y]=[b]$, and we want to conclude $\delta([x], [y]) = \delta([a], [b])$, that is, that $d(x,y) = d(a, b)$. But by definition, $x \sim a$ means $d(x, a) = 0$, which by the first property, means $x=a$, and similarly we get $y=b$. So in fact, $d(x, y) = d(a, b)$ simply because you have equality of the inputs.

Comment: The edit I made, do they make any difference?

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  The question seems to say that $x=y$ implies $d(x,y)=0$ but not conversely.  So the equivalence classes are sets of elements that are mutually at distance 0.

Comment: @MJD The OP edited the question.  It used to say $d(x,y) = 0 \iff x=y$.

Comment: I apologise for the confusion. The edited question is correct.

Comment: yes, it makes a difference. That's the remark I made at the end of my answer, and pretty much what I was asking in the comments. ;-)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein How would I do this then?

Comment: Using the triangle inequality, as Vincent demonstrates.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Once again I apologise for the edit